# How can I iterate through following JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, iteration

I have following `JSON` structure :

```
"123456789": {
"id": "Some_Id",
"code": "Some_Code",
"name": "Some_Name",
},
"123456789": {
"id": "Some_Id",
"code": "Some_Code",
"name": "Some_Name",
},,
"123456789": {
"id": "Some_Id",
"code": "Some_Code",
"name": "Some_Name",
}
}
```

Now if I have to find out name for every object inside `JSON`, how can I iterate?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Object.keys(theObject).forEach(function (key) {
  var item = theObject[key];
  console.log(item.name);
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: I think it's pretty much self explanatory, but you are free to edit and provide what you think is missing, that would be a much greater value than simply downvoting code answers.

Comment: (BTW I haven't downvoted, I came across this in LQP) I shouldn't edit as that would be clearly conflicting with the author's intent. This answer might also be useful to future viewers, but always an explanation can be provided. If you do not want to put an explanation, it's alright. I was just suggesting a way for your answer to be more better.

Answer (score -1):

You can use simple jQuery

```
arr = $.parseJSON(arr);
$.each(msg, function(i, key){
alert(key.id);
});
```

It is just an example to iterate

Comment: If you are casting down vote then give a reason at least

Answer (score -1):

> First of all, an object can not have multiple keys of same names.

Use [**`Object.keys`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get the keys of the object and iterate over them using [**`Array#foreach`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
var input = {
  "123456789": {
    "id": "Some_Id",
    "code": "Some_Code",
    "name": "Some_Name",
  },
  "123456789": {
    "id": "Some_Id",
    "code": "Some_Code",
    "name": "Some_Name",
  },
  "123456789": {
    "id": "Some_Id",
    "code": "Some_Code",
    "name": "Some_Name",
  }
};
console.log(Object.keys(input)) //Only one key
Object.keys(input).forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(input[item].name);
});
```

Comment: Come on! Will you mind stating the reason of _downvote_ ?

Comment: i tried this, but it runs only for the first object. It should run for all the id's. I didn't downvote :)

Comment: @Gaurav, As mentioned in the answer, an object can not have multiple with same name...

Comment: Thank it worked :)